# Dynamically copy row without modifying in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

**why**

creating a feature prioritization model in Google Sheets. Layout by sheet follows.

1. Just about the feature: summary, jira link, kano model values, etc.
2. Customers ranking for each feature
3. Sorted list of features based on customer demand (not in scope for this question)

**what**

Sheet 1 is where I input all feature requests.
Sheet 2 is where I'd like to rank all feature requests without having to copy and paste Sheet 1's summary row

What formula do I use so that Sheet 2, row A always = Sheet 1, row A?
Is it just each cell in Sheet 2, A pulls from Sheet 1, A? Like a massive copy and paste?

Is there a sort that doesn't sort? Or a transpose that doesn't transpose but just fills all the associated cells?

Answer (score 1):

You answered your question yourself. A transpose that doesn't transpose is equal to a double transpose, correct ? Something like `=Transpose(Transpose(Sheet1!A1:Z1000))`

or `=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A1:Z1000)`

Or use a query `=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:Z1000, "Select *")`, in some case this might behave strangely though, so I wouldn't recommend.